# Keeping passwords out of code but with gunicorn self-restartable?

Tags: django, security, gunicorn, fabric, supervisord

I am currently writing my fabric deploy script for my gunicorn/django app which is managed by supervisord. I have certain passwords that are required to be in the environment of the app when gunicorn runs.

It seems the standard way of doing things is to add environment variables to the [program:app] of /etc/supervisord/app.conf, but this means I will have plaintext passwords in my repo unless I kept the app.conf outside of the repo (which doesn't seem clean).

I can't hash the passwords because they are used by the app to access third party services. Also even if I kept app.conf outside of the repo, I still have plaintext passwords in app.conf which doesn't seem ideal.

Is there some way to let supervisord do its thing (restarting gunicorn on its own) without storing plaintext passwords?

Edit: Inevitably I need either the passwords or a way for supervisord to unlock the passwords, both of which can be used by attackers, so I think I will use something like AWS key management service so at least there is an extra step of getting to them.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used supervisord but I'm assuming you're just running a bash script to restart your server.

Create a file in your project folder called `.env` (the name doesn't really matter but it's convention). Make sure to add this file to your `.gitignore`.

In the env file, set any config vars:

```
#!/bin/bash

export ENV_VAR="value"
```

Then to use the env file, use `source .env`. This will apply any exported vars to your environment.